# How to compare two elements of a list using testng assert method

Tags: testng

```
@DataProvider(name="StringData")
public Object[][] StringProvider(){
    return new Object[][]{{"This is a real project with real "
            + "code to do real things to solve real "
        + "problems in real world real"}};
}

@Test(dataProvider="StringData")
public void testRepatedStrings(String s){
    List<String> lst = ReadString.RepeatedString(s);
```

"lst has two strings. i want to compare both elements of list lst using Assert.
anyone help me how to compare two elements of a list using assert function in testng"

Comment: Hi, what is this ReadString.RepeatedString(s); ? are you loading string twice into list and planning to compare both?

Answer (score 0):

The list class already has an implementation of equals method.  So list1.equals(list2) will result true if all the elements in the list match

```
Assert.assertEquals(list1,list2, "Lists don't match");
```

will also achieve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare more than one value in assert go with assert true , instead of assertEquals.
Ex :
**Assert.assertTrue((x==4) || (x==5)),"Unexpected Error");**

in the above example, it will be Pass if the value of x is either 4 or 5 else gives unexpected Error